# How to disable auto open window in Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin

when my friends write me a new conversation in pidgin open immediatly a new window.

Can I disable show a new window?

I want only a notify in tray ...

tnx

Answer (score 2):

If you set **Preferences/Interface/Conversation Window Hiding** to "**Always**" then new IM windows are suppressed. If you turn it to "**Never**" then the window would appear.